# Can we use deadlocks for anything?

Tags: process, transactions, deadlock

I was wondering about this. Deadlocks are something we prefer to avoid, but is there any scenario where we can use deadlocks to our advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) is a situation in which two or more competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does.

[image]

So your goal is to avoid falling into it. If your code result in a deadlock then you need to go back and do some code re-designing to avoid/minimize such deadlocks. Also it might be a good idea to have some kind of recovery & warning mechanism for when you hit a deadlock.

Now for your question: Can this be used for something? Well, there is always a good use for anything depends on your situation and your goal. Here are some scenarios:

- If you are a hacker who tries to attack some app, you can freeze the system by forcing it into many deadlocks.
- If you are a builder of some deadlock detecting system, you want then to generate such deadlocks in your testing environment to see if it will be caught by your system or not.

Answer (score 1):

NO!

A "deadlock" puts your code execution into a state where nothing can proceed.

(Warning, snarky comment: if that is what you want, just don't run the code).